# Why doOnSuccess can touch the ProgressBar even after set observeOn(Schedulers.io)

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Why `doOnSuccess` can touch the ProgressBar even after set `observeOn(Schedulers.io)`?

```
...
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.doOnSuccess(mainDataModel -> view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE))
```

I'm using Single observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`observeOn` affects downstream. It means it affects your `doOnSuccess` -> you are trying to do something about your view outside of the thread that created it (I'm guessing you are from Android ecosystem: in that case views are normally living on main thread, and correct scheduler for that would be `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`)